# Safari translate3d lags with scroll event

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, safari, css-transforms

I'm using a scroll event listener in Javascript to manually position an element when scrolling is done.

```
myContainerElement.addEventListener('scroll', function (e) {
  const transform = 'translate3d(' + this.scrollLeft + 'px,0,0)';
  scrollMyElement(transform);
});
```

Note that `scrollMyElement` just adds the transform to the element's style.
This works great on Firefox and Chrome, but I'm having issues with Safari. Using scroll wheel/touch pad OR scrollbar, the element seems to lag behind the rest of the page when scrolling.

I was able to fix this issue with the mouse wheel/touch pad by following this solution: [DOM element position slow while scrolling + difference between scrollbar-scrolling and mouse/touchpad-scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041685/dom-element-position-slow-while-scrolling-difference-between-scrollbar-scrolli)

So in Safari, it works great now with mouse wheel/touch pad, but still lags (just like the example in the solution posted above) when using scrollbar. How can I fix this?!

Things I have tried:

1. `-webkit-perspective: 1000;
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`
2. `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)` in addition for performance
3. Using all of the vendor prefixed transforms, like webkit, moz, o, ms.